# Django: return HttpResponseRedirect in get_queryset

Tags: python, django

I'm resolving a query in a search form. When the query yields only a single object, I want to redirect the user directly to the details page for that object. If not, they should land on the results page. I thought I'd do it as follows:

```
class ResultsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "chars/results.html"
    context_object_name = "chars"
    slug_field = 'name'

    def get_queryset(self):
        char = self.kwargs.pop('slug', '')
        object_list = get_list_or_404(Char, name=char)
        if len(object_list) > 1:
            return object_list

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('chars:details', args=(char,)))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and yields an empty bytestring (`b''`) to my template. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a thing you can do there. `get_queryset`, as the name implies, needs to return a queryset. You need to do this in a place that returns a response. One possibility is `get()`, but doing it there would mean you'd have to replicate a lot of the built-in functionality.

One alternative is `render_to_response` - I'm a bit torn because doing this conflicts with the name of that function, but it is quite a neat place to do it.

```
def render_to_response(self, context):
    if len(self.object_list) == 1:
        return redirect('chars:details', char)
    return super().render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking through the docs and figured it should be done in the `render_to_response()` method, however, I had no idea what the query result would be called by that stage (turns out it's `self.object_list`). Can you tell me where you found this?

Comment: A good reference is [ccbv.co.uk](http://ccbv.co.uk)  which lists all the class based views and their methods.

Comment: I get **AttributeError: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'filter'**